# Como faço para clicar num botão caso um target específico esteja lá?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Dependendo do CNPJ que eu carrego, ele gera uma âncora nova, com um ID diferente, aí eu preciso clicar nessa

```
<a id="menuPrincipal_divLinks3" title="" href="../Relatorio/GerarRelatorio.asp" target="palco">Gerar Relatório</a>
```

Como faço pra ele clicar apenas se o target for >gerar relatório< ?

Clicar pelo ID não da pq ele muda de ID dependendo do CNPJ, e pelo Xpath também não da, ele muda de posição

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer para resolver isso é:

1. Obter todos os links da página:

   links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

(Supondo que a variável usada para lidar com a página se chame *driver*)

2. Percorrer os links obtidos, e, obtendo o atributo *target*, clicar no link se o valor deste atributo for igual a "gerar relatório":

   ```
   #Supondo que a importação do webdriver foi feita com o nome de 'webdriver'
   wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10)

   for link in links:
     valor_target = link.get_attribute('target')

     if(valor_target == 'Gerar Relatório'): 
         try: #Para evitar TimeoutException
             espera = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(link)) 
             #A espera seria para evitar que ocorra ElementNotInteractableException
             link.click()
             #A linha abaixo também serve para evitar ElementNotInteractableException,
             #alternando a aba para a primeira que está aberta
             #(supondo que sua página ficará aberta na primeira aba)
             driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
         except TimeoutException as ex:
             print('Timeout excedido: ' + ex.msg)
   ```

Para rodar o código acima, você precisa fazer as seguintes importações:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Comment: Muito obrigado irmão